# Construction of Kähler submanifolds of Kähler manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I want to see how we can construct Kähler submanifolds of Kähler manifolds, i. e. what second fundamental form, metric, almost complex structure and connection satisfy in that case.
I am searching for the proper reference but unsuccessfully, I guess that is proved long time ago.
I would appreciate if you can recommend me a good reference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $X$ be a Kähler manifold and $Y \subseteq X$ a complex submanifold. Let $J$ be the almost complex structure on $X$ corresponding to its complex structure, then $J|_Y$ is the almost complex structure on $Y$ (this is precisely what it means for $Y$ to be a *complex* submanifold of $X$). Furthermore, if $h$ is the Kähler metric on $X$ with Kähler form $\omega$, then $h|_Y$ is a Kähler metric on $Y$ with Kähler form $\omega|_Y$. That is:

> Every complex submanifold of a Kähler manifold is Kähler.

In terms of references for this question and others related to Kähler geometry in general, here are some sources I recommend (in no particular order):

- Huybrechts, *Complex Geometry: An Introduction*,
- Moroianu, *Lectures on Kähler Manifolds*,
- Griffiths and Harris, *Principles of Algebraic Geometry*, and
- Demailly, *Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry* (pdf available [here](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf)).

You may also find [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630838/complex-and-kahler-manifolds/630894#630894) helpful.