# Kähler manifold structure on fibres

Tags: complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

I have read in my course notes the following statement :

> Let $p : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a holomorphic map between two complex manifolds. If $Y$ is a Kähler manifold then $\forall y\in Y$, $p^{-1}(y)$ is a Kähler manifold.

It is very vague, and assumptions are probably missing. I am trying to see when this might be true and what assumptions on $p$, $Y$ and $X$ should be added. For instance, it is clear that we should also require $p$ non constant.

First problem : $p^{-1}(y)$ isn't a submanifold of $X$ a priori. One case where it works, is when $X$ is a holomorphic fibre bundle  on $Y$, but can we take something weaker ?

Second problem : Suppose now we have the first problem settled and every fibre is a complex submanifold of $X$. Since the Kähler metric we would like to put on $p^{-1}(y)$ for all $y \in Y$ is the pullback of the one on $Y$, shouldn't we also require for $p$ to be an immersion?

Thanks in advance for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote will not work.

1. You should assume that $X$, not $Y$, is Kähler.
2. You should assume that $p$ is surjective and consider preimages of generic points in $Y$ (*generic fibers*), otherwise some of the preimages will not be submanifolds.

With this modification, the claim follows from Sard’s theorem (generic fibers are submanifolds) and the fact that complex submanifolds of a Kähler manifold are all Kähler.

See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437506/construction-of-k%C3%A4hler-submanifol).

Edit: 1. The Kähler metric (as well as the complex structure) on the fibers is **not** obtained by pull-back from the one on $Y$, it is obtained via pull-back from $X$ via inclusions $p^{-1}(y)\subset X$.

2. Yes, one way to avoid dealing with singular fibers is to assume that $p$ is a **submersion**: If you assume that $p$ is an *immersion* then all preimages  $p^{-1}(y)$ are discrete and the entire discussion becomes trivial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I must have made a mistake copying... Do you have reference or an idea for how to tackle my actual question, that is finding "weak" hypothesis on $p,X$ and $Y$ so that the statement makes sense ?

Comment: Your question, as stated, simply has negative answer. I do not think it can be saved. For instance, consider the product $X$ of a Kahler manifold $Y$ and a non-Kahler complex manifold $Z$. Take $p: X\to Y$, the coordinate projection.